# Как вывести два разных текста на два разных окна?

Tags: python, tkinter

в общем в функции ***init*** находится основное окно в котором есть выбор кнопок, при на нажатии на одну из них открывается другое окно с текстом(по идее), но на деле при нажатии на кнопку, новое окно(функция btn1_click) но в нём никакой текст не появляется, причём текст из главного окна заменяется на тот который указан в btn1_click.
Как это исправить?

```
class App(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super(App, self).__init__()
        self.title("Решатель задач 2999")
        self.geometry('600x400')
        self.resizable(0, 0)
        self.canvas = Canvas(self, height=600, width=400)
        self.canvas.pack()

        self.frame = Frame(self, bg='white')
        self.frame.place(relx=0, rely=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)

        self.btn1_count = 0
        self.btn2_count = 0

        title = Label(self.frame, text='Выберите вариант', bg='white')
        title.pack()
        self.btn1 = Button(self.frame, text='Встречное движение', bg='gray', font=50, command=self.btn1_click)
        self.btn1.pack(side=LEFT, padx=50)
        self.btn2 = Button(self.frame, text='Попутное движение', bg='gray', font=50, command=self.btn2_click)
        self.btn2.pack(side=RIGHT, padx=50)

    def btn1_click(self):
        if self.btn1_count > 0: return
        self.wnd1 = Toplevel()
        self.wnd1.title("Первый вариант")
        self.wnd1.geometry('600x400')
        self.wnd1.resizable(0, 0)
        self.wnd1.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.on_close1)
        canvas = Canvas(self.wnd1, height=600, width=400)
        canvas.pack()

        self.text = Frame(self, bg='white')
        self.text.place(relx=0, rely=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)

        wnd1 = Label(self.text, text='Введите данные \n неизвестное обознатче как x', bg='white')
        wnd1.pack()

        self.btn1_count += 1

    def on_close1(self):
        self.btn1_count -= 1
```

Comment: `self.text = Frame(self, bg='white')` - вы фрейм размещаете в основном окне, а не в дочернем `self.wnd1`